# Nginx and PHP-FPM deployed on EFS - Improve performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-eks, fpm, amazon-efs

I am running an application in the EKS cluster and I have nginx pods and applications pods (php5.6-fpm, laravel framework).
Application files are on EFS, which is mounted to the EKS cluster and to the pods. I was playing with different configurations of EFS, even provisioned 50mb IOPS, but sometimes I see performance degradation. Sometimes it takes 5 seconds to load the page and sometimes 1 second.

So a couple of questions if anyone has experience. Do you think that keeping files on EFS is a good idea? Is there any way to improve overall performance in my current setup?

Can you recommend any other solution than EFS? I need to run multiply nginx and application pods and ideally share the codebase, not to copy the the same files in each pod.

Comment: `...sometimes I see performance degradation` - can you elaborate how you measure EFS performance in relation to page load time?

Comment: @gohm'c i am running 2 sets of my application, dev1 is using efs, dev2 codebase is stored in pod filesystem, so the code base is not shared. I am executing performance scripts, and in dev2 response time is almost every time is the same. but dev1 have a higher response time and response time is jumping.

Comment: You can use cloudwatch to find the suspicious delay. Checkout my answer below.

Comment: @gohm'c yes we were running tests and found that EFS is downgrading the performance to about 300%. We had a big project ~1.5 GB and if this project is stored on EBS, average load of test heavy page takes 1,3 seconds. But if it is on EFS it takes about 4 - 4.5 seconds. WE run this test on multiply pages and I even provision 100MB/s throughput and still  EBS speed is much faster. I have read lots of articles and found that EFS is not good option to store big project

Answer (score 0):

Adding a front-end (Nginx) cache layer to the deployment configuration would be a good mitigation for a slow application.

The performance bottleneck is most likely caused by the specific PHP application, not the deployment configuration itself.  Try to identify what's happening when the page loads regarding CPU processing, database/network calls, etc.  Create a custom PHP page to benchmark performance that is independent of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Running in conjunction with your PHP performance scripts, you can measure the [EFS throughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/monitoring-cloudwatch.html) to see if there's any unexpected fluctuation **in relative** to the load time; and adjust to different [performance modes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-efs-performance-modes/) where applicable. A good tips is the adjustment to [read_ahead_kb size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance-tips.html) on the host.